# How do I interpret the output of sparsenn?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I just came across sparsenn, http://lowrank.net/nikos//sparsenn/. I followed a blog (http://fastml.com/a-bag-of-words-and-a-nice-little-network/) and ran it over my dataset. But I'm not able to interpret the results completely. The blog does mention that the output consists of accuracy, RMSE and AUC as output values. Sample output:

pass 0 tacc 0.61577 sacc 0.62698 trms 0.96398 srms 0.95736 tauc 0.65859 sauc 0.68796

But what specifically, is the difference between tacc and sacc, trms and srms, and tauc and sauc? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code:

```
 at=acc(pt, train.target, train.nex);
 et=rms(pt, train.target, train.nex);
 rt=auc(pt, train.target, train.nex);
 as=acc(ps, stop.target, stop.nex);
 es=rms(ps, stop.target, stop.nex);
 rs=auc(ps, stop.target, stop.nex);
 printf("pass %d tacc %.5f sacc %.5f trms %.5f srms %.5f tauc %.5f sauc %.5f ",i,at,as,et,es,rt,rs);
```

You'll see that the t* variables refer to the metrics on the training set, while the others (s* for stop) refer to the metrics on the validation set.